# Manipulate string from /etc/redhat-release

Tags: php, linux, centos, version

Some obvious code omitted. When i do the following it is to get the version of Linux running on a remote machine.

```
$filedes = ssh2_exec($connection, "cat /etc/redhat-release");
stream_set_blocking($filedes, true);  
$stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($filedes, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
$blah = nl2br(stream_get_contents($filedes));
```

So this works fine and where

```
$blah = nl2br(stream_get_contents($filedes));
```

I get retunened the information i asked for form the remote command above.

```
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
```

However any code i put immediately after that, $blah is blank. Why is that? Why isn't

```
$blah = "CentOS release 6.7 (Final)";
```

I want ot manipulate the string but its empty.

Answer (score 1):

I was typing this it it occurred to me. nl2br() function is messing it all up, and it was.

nl2br() is new line to <br>

i removed that and now the variable stays set.